# Sharing a video from an URI

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android app that lets the user choose a video from his device and after that share the video to other people. I want to save the path of the video so next time the user opens the app he will only need to press the share button.
I succeeded to do the first part, and saved the Uri as a string with SharedPreferences, but when I go back to the app, after closing, and try to share, the app crash.
I understand it happen because I don't give the right permission. But I tried all I found in google but didn't get into solution.

my code:

```
Main2Activity.this.grantUriPermission("com.whatsapp", selectedVideo, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        Intent shareVideo = new Intent();
        shareVideo.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareVideo.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        shareVideo.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        shareVideo.putExtra("jid", PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators("972"+phoneNumber) + "@s.whatsapp.net");
        shareVideo.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, selectedVideo);
        shareVideo.setType("video/*");
        shareVideo.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                getString(R.string.user_name) + " : " + userName + "\n" +
                        getString(R.string.user_email) + " : " + userEmail + "\n" +
                        getString(R.string.user_phone_number) + " : " + userPhoneNumber + "\n");
        startActivity(shareVideo);
```

Comment: Check this doc https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#java and this https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file

Comment: I checked those docs several times and didn't get to the right way to do it.